# Site without "www" is hacked !

Tags: php, security

A site with www.site.com (make with php)works normally but without www  "site.com" has been hacked. How can I clean injection?
Thanks

Comment: You should be more specific about your server, etc

Comment: is it a php-nuke site?

Answer (score 2):

www.site.com and site.com are different domain names. *Usually* they point to the same site, but that's not necessarily the case.

Comment: Yep, he certainly has a weird DNS configuration for this to happen.

Comment: @nc3b 
How can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The `www` (world wide web) has nothing to do with it, it seems that at your side, there is url rewriting in place or some server settings in place disallowing you to use `www` part there by giving the message hacked. Please add more details so that we can answer better.